# How to add a subdomain pointing to IP of EC2 instance in AWS where the domain is pointing to the IP of the machine of some other hosting provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

**Here is the situation -**

1. I have my domain name xyz.com purchased from godaddy which is pointing to the website IP hosted by wix.com. 2 nameservers provided are of wix.com i.e. - ns2.wixdns.net & ns3.wixdns.net.
2. I have another website which is hosted in AWS EC2 instance with some IP say XX:XX:XX:XX

I want to create a subdomain **sub.xyz.com** which should point to the IP(XX:XX:XX:XX) of my AWS EC2 instance without affecting the main domain pointing to the website created through wix.com.

**Things I did, but did not work -**

1. I tried to contact godaddy for this purpose but they said it has to be done through AWS
2. Tried to use subdomain option on godaddy and created a subdomain record for sub.xyz.com for the IP address of the EC2 instance
3. Checked on internet and got some articles stating use of Route 53 on AWS. I tried to create one hosted zone file with xyz.com domain name but it created 4 new nameservers. Then I created a record set for this using -

name = sub.xyz.com,

record type = A-IPv4 Address,

TTL=300,

Value = XX:XX:XX:XX (IP of EC2 instance),

Routing policy = Simple

Route 53 provided 4 new nameservers which I think if I update on godaddy then it will not point domain name xyz.com to the website hosted by wix.com

I do not have much knowledge about AWS and domain/subdomain routing.

Comment: Point 2. should be enough. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes. But it did not work. Tried contacting Godaddy team but they said that I need to set the subdomain pointing from the web hosting provider.

Comment: But they even have a manual for it: https://uk.godaddy.com/help/add-a-subdomain-that-points-to-an-ip-address-4080

Comment: I already tried it. It is not working. Our DNS is hosted by wix.com

Comment: Ah, OK. then just create sub.xyz.com A record in Wix DNS.

Comment: Correct. By the time I saw your last answer I tried creating A record for the subdomain on Wix and it worked. Thanks anyways.

Comment: If you got answer, please add it as answer and accept it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying and as commented by Dusan above, creating 'A' record for "sub.xyz.com" in WIX resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create sub.xyz.com A record in Wix DNS.

As commented by - Dusan Bajic

Comment: You've posted the answer 6 hours back whereas I posted the answer on July 15, also I mentioned the source. The reason I put it in answer was others could have more visibility. Who posted other people's answer here? I didn't post others answer but took it from comments.

Comment: OK. I apologize. I did not see your answer earlier. Thanks.