# (AWS) Point only root domain to Wix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, velo

So I was to host my main website with Wix, but I want to maintain subdomains in AWS. For example:

example.com -> Wix website
api.example.com -> Load balancer

How can this be accomplished? Thanks in advance!

[Edit] I should mention that the domain is not registered with Wix. It’s actually registered with Google, and the DNS is configured for AWS

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to create a third-level domain (often called a "subdomain") name A record in Wix DNS.

Is this the same scenario here: [How to add a subdomain pointing to IP of EC2 instance in AWS where the domain is pointing to the IP of the machine of some other hosting provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101261/how-to-add-a-subdomain-pointing-to-ip-of-ec2-instance-in-aws-where-the-domain-is?rq=1)

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that the domain is not registered with Wix. It’s actually registered with Google, and the DNS is configured for AWS